# Django - site maps with slug from DB

Tags: django, seo, sitemap

My app includes a dynamic slug url - `http://mydomain.com/<slug>` where slug is a parameter in the `'name'` field of a model in the database.

I then have a 'detail view' that takes the slug and a further detail - `http://mydomain.com/<slug>/<detail>`.

The corresponding URL conf sections are:

```
url(r'^(?i)(?P<slug>[\w\.\--]*)/?$', views.list, name="list"),
url(r'^(?i)(?P<slug>[\w\.\--]*)/(?P<detail>[\w\.-]*)/?$', views.detail, name="detail"),
```

I was wondering how I can define the sitemap dictionary for this.

Answer (score 1):

This link was very helpful for me.

https://skyl.org/log/post/skyl/2010/03/add-urls-to-your-django-sitemap-that-require-two-objects/

Essentially, I extended the sitemap.Sitemap class in order to override the items function with my desired queryeset (i.e. `Model.objects.all()`). I then also overrided the location function to `return '/%s/' % obj.name`